# Knockout template name building

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I am using jQuery.tmpl and Knockout. Inside jQuery tmpl template I am using Knockout binding as follows:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'field-String'}"></div>
```

I need to have dynamic template name. How can I achieve this?

I tried with no luck:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'field-${Type}'}"></div>
```

Comment: What is Type? Is it a ko.observable? If yes, you can try with <div `data-bind="template: { name: 'field-' + Type()}"></div>`

Comment: It is not observable !BUT! it worked out for me with this case: 'field-' + Type. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the  jQuery.tmpl syntax here, you can just use plain string concatenation to build your template name:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'field-' + Type }"></div>
```

Note: if your `Type` is an `ko.observable` you need to write: `name: 'field-' + Type()`